# Select from database where date is less than a supplied date

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, date

I'm trying to pull rows from a database where the date is within two weeks of the current date, I'm using CodeIgniter and this is my model:

```
function GetToDoItems($userID)
{
  $range = date('Y-m-d', strtotime("+2 weeks"));
  $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM FYP_Milestones
                            INNER JOIN FYP_Modules ON FYP_Milestones.ModuleID = FYP_Modules.ID
                            WHERE FYP_Milestones.MilestoneDue < $range
                            ORDER BY FYP_Milestones.MilestoneDue ASC
                            ");
  return $query->result();
}
```

It runs this query:

```
SELECT * FROM FYP_Milestones INNER JOIN FYP_Modules ON FYP_Milestones.ModuleID = FYP_Modules.ID WHERE FYP_Milestones.MilestoneDue < 2016-04-14 ORDER BY FYP_Milestones.MilestoneDue ASC
```

I have a row in the database like so:
[image]

Considering 2016-04-07 is less than 2016-04-14 by 7 days I'm expecting that row alone to be pulled, **but SQL is returning an empty result** , why is this the case?

Answer (score 5):

You actually don't need PHP for the range, use SQL:

```
WHERE FYP_Milestones.MilestoneDue < (CURDATE() + INTERVAL 2 WEEK)
```

Comment: It's faster and makes more sense to do it this way rather than in PHP

Answer (score 1):

Add single quotes to the date value like:

```
$query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM FYP_Milestones
                        INNER JOIN FYP_Modules ON FYP_Milestones.ModuleID = FYP_Modules.ID
                        WHERE FYP_Milestones.MilestoneDue < '".$range."'
                        ORDER BY FYP_Milestones.MilestoneDue ASC
                        ");
```